# Desconfiguração na importação de um ficheiro CSV, usando o Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, opencsv

Boa noite,
Eu pretendo importar ficheiro em excel, para depois poder manipular, mas quando faço a importação da planilha no Pycharm o ficheiro fica todo desconfigurado.
Alguem me pode ajudar?
Segue em anexo o print[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Ou existe outro iddle melhor para manipulação de dados?

Cumprimentos

Comment: Você pode manipular seus datasets também através do Jupyter Notebook direto no browser https://jupyter.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Problema não é da IDE, você esta lendo um arquivo CSV e o Python está lendo o arquivo corretamente. Você precisa é formatar a saída para o modo que você queira.

Se me lembro bem na documentação do Panda existe alguns exemplos  e aqui tb https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read_csv-load-data-from-csv-files/